# How to initialize NSTableRowView subclass?

Tags: cocoa, nstablerowview

The compiler crashses on line 3 and I cant find information on NSTableRowView initializers anywhere

```
class ItemRowView: NSTableRowView {
    convenience override init(frame: NSRect) {
        self.init(frame: frame) // EXC BAD ACCESS
        self.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle.None
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `init( frame: NSRect )`is the *designated* initializer, so the keyword `convenience` is wrong in this place.
Then you probably meant to call the `super` initializer than your own method recursively.
At last you'll need to implement another required initializer `init?(coder: NSCoder)`

The following code should get you going:

```
class ItemRowView: NSTableRowView {
    override init(frame: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame) // super - not self
        self.draggingDestinationFeedbackStyle = NSTableViewDraggingDestinationFeedbackStyle.None
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        // Write something useful here, or leave the default implementation
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: That errors. I need to delegate to a designated initialiser using `self.init` from the convenience initialiser. However no designated initialiser is being inherited and I dont know how to write my own implementation.

Comment: Well, you are already overriding the designated initializer. See [NSView Class Reference - initWithFrame:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/initWithFrame:). If you delete the `convenience` keyword and add another required initializer it will work. I'll update the answer accordingly.